# Recyclerview слетает анимация с элемента при скроллинге списка

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Необходимо задать анимацию нажатому элементу списка.
Я делаю это так:

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View view, int index) {
       view.startAnimation(animation);
    }
```

но когда прокручиваю список элементов Recyclerview анимация останавливается.
P.S анимация у меня зациклена, т.е нажимаю на элемент и она выполняется пока я не нажму на другой элемент и т.д

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
        case 0:
            posInList = position / 2;
           Picasso.with(mContext).load(imageModel.get(posInList)).resize(320, 320)
                    .into(holder.getItemImageView());

            break;
        case 2:
            break;
    }

}
```

Анимация:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="true">
<scale
    android:duration="500"
    android:fillBefore="true"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:startOffset="0"
    android:toXScale="0.9"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:toYScale="0.9" />
```

Comment: Вам нужен метод onAttach чего-то там в адаптере. В нем надо заново стартануть анимацию. Ну и хранить где-то какие пункты надо анимировать

Comment: @ЮрийСПб
не полностью Вас понял,может есть пример?

Comment: Примера нет, а вот всю нужную вам информацию о том как надо сделать написал в ответ. Собственно весь пример должен заключаться в том что `view.startAnimation(animation)` надо вызвать в методе `onViewAttachedToWindow`. Только там вам надо ещё всякие условия проверить. А это уже без знания что у вас в коде и как написать невозможно.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб
хм..интересно одно,если я в `onBindViewHolder` сделаю так
`holder.getItemImageView().startAnimation(anim);`
то анимация применяется ко всем элементам и при скролле не пропадает

Comment: Ну да, по идее можно и в onBindViewHolder стартовать анимацию если нужно. Но вам всё равно надо хранить информацию о том какие ячейки надо анимировать.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб
только как применить анимацию к нужному мне элементу в `onBindViewHolder`. По клику я знаю...тут нет...

Comment: Ну вы ж вешаете слушатель нажатий на эту вьюху? Типа так `holder.view.setOnClickListener(...);` Вот также и анимацию стартуйте. `holder.view.startAnimation(animation);`

Comment: @ ЮрийСПб
так я же вам говорю,что этот способ воспроизведет для всех элементов анимацию

Comment: Ну а я вам раза 4 сказал что вам надо сохранять позиции элементов анимируемых и запускать анимацию только для них.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб
получается,если делать как вы предлагаете,то это постоянно придется дергать sharedpreferences...не вариант

Comment: Нам неизвестно какие данные вы отображаете в списке. Если это у вас список кастомных объектов у которых есть `boolean isAnimated` которое меняется при нажатии, то просто его проверяйте. Тут `SharedPreferences` не нужны. Если это у вас массив примитивов каких-то, то создайте рядом массив `boolean[]` и в нём ечейкам меняйте значения при клике и его проверяйте по позиции.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб
коллекция изображений,метода проверки никакого нет,я просто по нажатию воспроизвожу анимацию...все просто

Comment: Вот так же просто создайте коллекцию `Boolean` и при простом нажатии нужному элементу присваивайте true в коллекции

Comment: В общем вам надо поискать тут на сайте вопросы про чекбоксы и ListView там написано что как и зачем делать.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо ЮрийСПб за совет. Сделал так:

```
private SparseBooleanArray mSparseBooleanArray;
 construktor(){
mSparseBooleanArray = new SparseBooleanArray();
 }

 onBindViewHolder(){
    if (mSparseBooleanArray.get(posInList)){
                holder.getItemImageView().startAnimation(anim);
            }
  }


 public void itemClicked(int item){
    mSparseBooleanArray.clear();
    mSparseBooleanArray.put(item,true);
}
```

в итоге: анимация не слетает при скроллинге

Answer (score 0):

При скроле списка и ухода ячейки за край экрана она открепляется системой от разметки. При этом вызывается метод `onViewDetachedFromWindow(ViewHolderClass holder)` - в нём вы можете останавливать анимации, выгружать картинки и делать прочие вещи для избежания утечек памяти. В качестве аргумента приходит определённый вами в адаптере холдер указанного вами типа. Если их у вас несколько - то вам надо соамостоятельно скастовать пришедший к нужному. Из холдера же вы можете получить `position` метода `getAdapterPosition()`.

Точно также работает и нужный вам `void onViewAttachedToWindow(ViewHolderClass holder)` - он вызывается когда ранее откреплённая от разметки вьюха ячейки списка снова прикрепляется к оному при появлении на экране в процессе скрола. Именно в этом методе вам надо скастовать пришедший в аргументе холдер к вашему типу и, в случае если нужно, запустить анимацию снова, т.к. она останавливается при откреплении вью от разметки. Определять какую ячейку надо анимировать а какую нет вам придётся самостоятельно - храните в адаптере, например, индексы анимируемых элементов.

Comment: `Ну а я вам раза 4 сказал что вам надо сохранять позиции элементов анимируемых и запускать анимацию только для них.`
что вы подразумеваете под позицией?
`holder.getAdapterPosition()` -это ,не сталкивался с таким просто